# Why is USB High Speed considered differential and what is its common mode?

Tags: usb

I am reading USB 2.0 standard, particularly about High-speed part, and I can't understand why do we consider that High-speed USB uses differential signaling. Or at least why it is balanced? For transmitting logic 0 or 1, USB transmitter drives either one line or another with 17.7mA, and if said differential, I would expect currents with the same intensity but opposite directions.
Because of my previous problems to understand this issue, I am not able to understand what is than a common mode on the USB bus in High-speed mode.

Comment: It's implicit that when one line is driving 17.7ma the other line will be sinking 17.7ma.

The common mode voltage is the voltage present on EACH of the wires i.e. if one wire was at 3.7v and one at 2.5v you have a common mode voltage of 2.5v and a differential voltage of 1.2v.

Comment: I wouldn't say so. The standard says: "In order to transmit in high-speed mode, a transceiver activates an internal current source which is derived from its positive supply voltage and directs this current into one of the two data lines via a high speed current steering switch." Also, when you look in the eye diagram of the USB, the signal goes +-400mv, and in the case that opposite currents flow in both D+ and D- lines, it would produce differential voltage of +-800mV.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of the document you are reading this from? * Found it, main spec document for usb 2.0

Comment: Universal Serial Bus 2.0 Specification, chapter 7.1, some paragraphs down from the beginning.

Comment: @MichaelShaw in your example we'd normally say the common mode voltage is 3.2 V.

Comment: I feel like I have unlearned some stuff in looking to this, I'm no longer sure! Figure 7-1 shows the "High speed current driver" with an output connected to D+ and a !output connected to D-, I think this means the current is flowing in a circle. I hope someone can give you a more affirmative answer.

Comment: Dear world, yes, common mode voltage is (v1 + v2) / 2. Please pardon my brainfart. @ThePhoton the correct number is 3.1V, thanks again for spotting my initial mistake.

Comment: Related: [Why does differential signaling send complementary signals instead of just pairing the input and ground voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/122138/6334)

Comment: @ThePhoton I understand the idea of differential signaling, but considering what is written in the USB specification, they are not having balanced signal, at least I cant find the evidence of having opposite currents in D+ and D- lines at the same time.

Comment: @Nexy_sm, You're right the text isn't very clear. Figure 7-6 seems to imply that even though the signals are offset at the driver, they will be balanced when they arrive at the receiver. But there doesn't seem to be any discussion of Fig 7-6 in the (nearby) text, so I'm not really clear how that's supposed to happen. I'm not expert on USB, though, so it might be explained in there somewhere.

Comment: The 17.7 mA is not for Full-speed, it is for High-speed mode, where everything is meant to be properly terminated, 2 x 45 Ohms to ground, or 90 Ohm differential. Could you clear up the question?

Answer (score 3):

USB signaling is called differential because it is differential. The state of bus is either one line (D+) is HIGH, the other (D-) is LOW. And vice versa. The receiver is connected in a differential way, and senses either positive DIFFERENCE, or negative. So it is differential.

The idea that current should be either sourced or sunk is fairly narrow. For example, the very popular [LVDS signaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-voltage_differential_signaling) uses two levels on each of signal pair of wires, VH is 1.4 V, and VL is 1.0 V. Yet no one is questioning differentiality of this signaling standard.

Same in USB: for FS signaling mode, VH is 3.3 V, VL is 0 V on each individual wire. An the packets use alternative states (called J and K) to transmit information. The receiver senses either +3.3 V, or -3.3 V.

For the HS signaling the VH is 400 mV, VL is 0 mV, so the differential signal goes from +400 mV to -400 mV.

CORRECTION: In both cases the common-mode signal is half of nominal voltage swing. Section 7.1.4.2 of USB 2.0 Specifications explicitly mentions that nominal common-mode voltage for HS signaling is 200 mV.

When BOTH USB wires have additional offset, for example, due to signal shift in ground return wire (due to power supply current, which happens on bus-powered devices on long and/or skinny cables), the receiver must tolerate this within USB specified limits.

Comment: The common-mode is not zero, but the mean of the voltages.

Comment: Well, it might be that I didn't understand differential signaling while at university, but I am pretty sure that in order to say some signaling scheme is differential it should have balanced currents in the lines, so that almost no current flows to the ground. Why I think USB is not differential signaling is because when sending 1, current flows from the current source through 45 ohm resistors at both ends of the transmission linea dn goes to the ground. The other line is passive, which means during one bit period, we do not have opposite sign currents which flows through both D+ and D- lines

Comment: @Nexy_sm even if there's a net DC current, the AC current to produce the actual signalling transitions would be fairly symmetric since the lines are changing in opposition, and that is largely the most important.

Comment: @Nexy_sm, every signaling over a pair of wires has two parameters - differential voltage swing, and common mode voltage. So different can be the terminations - differential termination, and common-mode termination. Ground currents depend on the way how the lines are terminated. The differential signaling can be balanced, or can be unbalanced, http://www.edn.com/design/analog/4335533/Understanding-common-mode-signals . Yes, USB uses unbalanced differential signaling, but it is still differential..

Comment: Note that there are symbols in USB that have both D+ and D- at the same level.

Comment: @SimonRichter, yes, there is a state of SE0 - Single Ended Zero, although it is not called "symbol", just EOP - End Of Packet. Every LS/FS packet ends with this state.  However, the state with both D+ and D- **high** is strictly illegal in the USB framework. Therefore the relatively infrequent occurrence of both Dp/Dm at zero doesn't contradict the general spirit of my answer. Yes, USB signaling schema is somewhat eclectic, no argument here.

Answer (score 0):

Common Mode voltage refers to both the AC and DC mean voltage "common to both" conductors.

The DC mean voltage is obvious when you see the levels, but of greater significance is the use of CML or current mode logic at high speeds where instead of using a voltage source with an RdsOn of 25 Ohms or so, it uses a current source switched between outputs that creates a voltage in the terminators on the bus, so that it is matched to the cable impedance and gives the best immunity from RF noise and lowest emissions of the RF signals.

CML is an offshoot improvement in CMOS from the bipolar days of ECL where differential current lines were used for > 1GHz speeds.

CML is not specifically mentioned in the spec, and there may some specific differences, but conceptually it is identical.

Learning the significance of CMRR on cables and differential impedance as well CM impedance differences are key to understanding how high error rates are achieved with wide eye-patterns from cable non-linearities. (kinks etc) and why 3m is the max length for USB3.

...but that's an inference to a deeper question.

Answer (score 0):

USB *is* differential.

As we use less and less power to transmit signals, we use lower voltages to get higher speed signals and better energy efficiency.

The penalty is that those signals become more susceptible to interference.
Differential lines give us less radiated signal from our transmission line and more immunity from incoming interference.

Twisting the differential pair makes it even more immune.

Comment: You didn't even try to respond to the question's concern about the return current.  Please read the whole question before answering, not just the title.

Answer (score 0):

USB is both differential, and not.

Disclaimer: I haven't seen the internal diagram of a typical USB receiver structure, so I don't know exactly how they solve the common mode and differential input conditions.  Discovering this would likely require either decapping some ICs (and taking very good micrographs of them to resolve the transistors -- may require an electron microscope), or licensing such structures from a company that has designed them (in which case, one's own curiosity may be satisfied, but other than vague hints (or maybe not even that), licensing terms will strictly prohibit sharing any information with others).

It isn't clear [to me] that Full Speed or High Speed signals are necessarily handled any differently from simply two normal logic inputs (of respective threshold levels).  Or four, wherein two receivers are set for the SE0 threshold, and the other two are either referenced absolute (half the logic level, i.e. VCC/2 for Full Speed, 200mV for High Speed), or one receiver is used, referenced to each other (i.e. a proper differential receiver).

It would at least be easiest to implement, by using one single LVDS-style receiver, with full common mode range (i.e. V<sub>ICM</sub> from 0 to VCC), which can therefore resolve inputs as low as a few hundred mV (High Speed), and up (the ±3.3V of Full Speed).

Is USB differential?

If the above assumptions turn out to be typical of real receivers, then yes, data is received differentially during a data packet.

Is USB truly differential?

No, it is not differential, because the data can be corrupted by common mode noise on the line.

Since the SE0 signal must override the data signal for it to be sensed at all, the common mode range of USB data transmission is, at best, between that threshold and VCC.

Notice also, that for a transmitter to launch a SE0 symbol with good signal quality, it must drive both lines low with respect to the cable shield and/or supply wires.  *The cable shield must not be compromised, such a signal is fully common-mode, and therefore CM filtering cannot be employed.*

(You do see USB CMCs from time to time; these are designed for quite low impedances (say 30-120 ohms), basically a dual-line ferrite bead moreso than a CMC like would be used for CAN or RS-485 (which might be some kohms).  This is not just intentional, but necessary, because a higher impedance would corrupt the SE0 symbol.  This amount is a compromise between improving data quality during a packet, and worsening SE0 quality at the start/end of a packet.)

---

To better understand this, requires a more general understanding of differential lines, and receivers used to sense them.

What is a voltage difference?  It is simply the voltage between two points.  As long as the receiver can understand that voltage drop, it can receive data bits correctly.

A typical input structure (a comparator, more or less) has a working (common mode) input range (V<sub>ICM</sub>) between its supply rails.  Beyond this range, either input ESD clamp diodes are forward-biased, shorting out the difference, or the input structure itself loses bias (for example, exceeding the working range of the current sources/sinks biasing a differential pair).

A receiver driven beyond its V<sub>ICM</sub> cannot very well be said to be differential anymore, can it?

So what value, then, is differential signaling?

*As long as we can meet certain assumptions, we can take advantage of the cancellation of noise on the line.*

Namely, that:

1. Common mode can be ignored in normal use, and
2. Common mode noise shall be less than V<sub>ICM</sub>.

For LVDS, typical receivers have this rail-to-rail range, so for noise less than about a volt, signals will be received correctly.  This is an acceptable  noise level for on-board signals: differential pairs spanning across a PCB will pick up noise from various sources, like nearby traces, crossing over gaps between power or ground planes, or induction from local ground loops (say near a powerful IC, or an SMPS section).

Differential pairs work, not by reducing noise on the line, but by exposing both lines to equal amounts of noise (and at the same position along the trace), so that the noise can be subtracted out by the receiver.

Typical on-board noise sources will be fractions of 100mV, so a CM range of a volt or more is perfectly adequate for board-level use.  (And that'd be a noisy enough board that I'd be asking for a re-spin!)

Note that LVDS, and other true(er)-differential standards like RS-485 and Ethernet, are responsive *only* to the differential signal, as long as the input range is satisfied, and nothing else.

RS-485 typically uses the same sort of input structure, but augments its voltage range (to +12/-7V or more) by using voltage divider resistors.  This introduces some loading on the line -- hence receivers are rated in terms of "unit load" per the standard's receiver specifications, and there is a maximum number of such loads on the line before signal level is degraded too far.  The divider also reduces comparator gain and bandwidth some, hence their typical ~100mV input threshold range.  Bandwidth is not too bad considering, with 20Mbps receivers being common.

Ethernet is the fullest kind of differential seen so far: using transformers, it has absolutely no galvanic connection at all between receiver and line!  The same is true of course for RS-485 and others, when an isolated interface is used.

Anyway, considering USB in these terms: it violates both points 1 and 2 above: a common-mode signal is used as an intentional and necessary part of the system; and it is not tolerant of CM noise, nor can it be CM filtered [to an arbitrary degree].

---

There is regrettably a tremendous amount of misinformation about this topic out there.  Even on -- perhaps especially on -- platforms like StackExchange here.  This is a perfect opportunity to recommend caution when using these websites.  *No one needs to be correct to write an answer,* and even blatantly incorrect answers still garner upvotes from non-experts when they are written believably enough.  (Incidentally, the same concern applies to AI-generated content these days.  Which... approaching that argument from this angle, well, let's just say I don't see it as much cause for concern.)  Be critical of everything; critical thinking is a skill like any other, and it must be practiced regularly.  When something is presented as fact, consider: how do they know that?  Where could they have read that?  How could they have figured that out?  Does it check out, is it consistent with its own reasoning?  Does it check out with references, and why or why not?  And recursively: how would the references know?  Did they measure it, and if so did they measure the right thing, make appropriate inferences, etc.?  This is the process of science.